# Cannot run PySide Qt program inside PyCharm IDE. Have to run from shell using pythonw or python.app

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pycharm

I made a simple 'pst.py' (hello world) program inside Pycharm.   When I run it, it crashes with:

> Qt internal error: qt_menu.nib could not be loaded. The .nib file
>   should be placed in QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/  or in
>   the resources directory of your application bundle.

Inside PyCharm, from an Python Console, all the modules look available:

```
>>>     print(PySide.QtCore.qVersion())
4.7.4
>>> print(PySide.__version__)
1.1.2
```

So I went to the terminal and tried running the same program from the command line using 'python.app' and 'pythonw.'  The program worked fine using both **python.app** and **pythonw**   If I used just **python pst.py**, I got the same crash.

```
vt102:dBaseProject sloter$ python.app pst.py
vt102:dBaseProject sloter$ which python.app
/Users/sloter/anaconda/bin/python.app

vt102:dBaseProject sloter$ pythonw pst.py
vt102:dBaseProject sloter$ which pythonw
/Users/sloter/anaconda/bin/pythonw
```

I think that PyCharm IDE is using the same path (Users/sloter/anaconda/bin/)

[image]

I watched a youtube video where a guy wrote a very similar program inside PyCharm and then ran inside Pycharm and things worked fine.

So any ideas what I need to change to enable me to develop PySide/QT program entirely inside PyCharm?

Thanks

ps here's the code for   'pst.py' that I tried to run

```
#!/Users/sloter/anaconda/bin/python

# Import PySide classes
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *


# Create a Qt application
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# Create a Label and show it
label = QLabel("Hello World")
label.show()
# Enter Qt application main loop
app.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Have you tried this shebang: `#!/Users/sloter/anaconda/bin/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python`?

Comment: Also, have you used macdeployqt?

Comment: The directory `/Users/sloter/anaconda/bin/python.app` doesn't exist.  python.app is a file not a directory.    I am not sure what macdeployqt "deployment" actually does -- I thought I illustrated (proved?)  with the `print(PySide.QtCore.qVersion())
4.7.4 =>>> print(PySide.__version__) =1.1.2`   that Qt support was correctly installed.   But maybe I don't understand deployment.

Comment: Moreover,  since it works from the commandline, but not pycharm ide, made me think the problem was there, not in the installation (deployment?) of Qt.

Comment: have you tried to do the copy or use macdeployqt?

Comment: no, because it's not clear what either of those two things does or how they relate to each other.  I'm afraid of random shell incantations before i know what it's trying to do.

Comment: Same problem here. I've done the copy but that's only relevant once you've compiled the code. I'm also just trying to get a normal write/debug code workflow going in PyCharm with PySide.

Answer (score 0):

> Qt internal error: qt_menu.nib could not be loaded. The .nib file should be placed in QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/ or in the resources directory of your application bundle.

One way to get you going would be this:

```
mkdir -p application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/
cp -r $(QTLIBDIR)/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Resources/qt_menu.nib application.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/
```

In general, I would personally suggest to use macdeployqt if you happen to copy these manually.